# What is a clean and concise way to get all id's of a given class, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get an array of all element ID's of elements of a given class (e.g. "main-menu-item"). This is what I have so far:

`Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".main-menu-item"), (elem => elem.id));`

Is there a cleaner and/or more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the spread operator:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".main-menu-item")].map(elem => elem.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with the mapping function, allowing you to convert the NodeList into an array while also specifying how each element should be transformed:

```js
const res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".main-menu-item"), ({id}) => id);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<p class="main-menu-item" id="1">one</p>
<p class="main-menu-item" id="2">two</p>
<p class="main-menu-item" id="3">three</p>
```

Comment: I ran this alongside Daniel Rodriguez Meza's solution on jsbench.me and this one turned out fastest more often than not. But both solutions are extremely close and it all comes to which syntax you are more accustomed to.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I guess the spread then map option presented in Daniel's code does two loops in total of the array contents, one for spreading the content into the array, and the other for mapping, so a total of 2N operations, whereas this does the converting to an array and mapping in the one loop, so its just N operations. At the end of the day, they're both linear-time O(N), so performance is not really going to be a big difference between the two pieces of code when the number of elements becomes large.

Comment: While both answers were correct and helpful, I decided I liked Daniel's answer the best (even though it might be slightly slower) because it was more obvious to me what it was doing. Thanks to both of you!